# Error in parsing JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

I am scrapping data from website. The data we are getting is in the format of

```
[
[
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "7:26pm",
        "depStation": "Albion Park Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "7:46pm",
        "arrStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "1"
    },
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "8:00pm",
        "depStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "9:14pm",
        "arrStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    },
    {
        "train": "Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "9:20pm",
        "depStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "depPlatform": "3",
        "arrTime": "9:24pm",
        "arrStation": "Kogarah Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    },
    {
        "train": "Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "9:27pm",
        "depStation": "Kogarah Station ",
        "depPlatform": "4",
        "arrTime": "9:31pm",
        "arrStation": "Allawah Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "4"
    }
],
[
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "7:26pm",
        "depStation": "Albion Park Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "7:46pm",
        "arrStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "1"
    },
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "8:00pm",
        "depStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "9:14pm",
        "arrStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    },
    {
        "train": "Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "9:30pm",
        "depStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "depPlatform": "3",
        "arrTime": "9:32pm",
        "arrStation": "Allawah Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    }
],
[
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "8:16pm",
        "depStation": "Albion Park Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "8:38pm",
        "arrStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "1"
    },
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "8:54pm",
        "depStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "10:14pm",
        "arrStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    },
    {
        "train": "Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "10:30pm",
        "depStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "depPlatform": "3",
        "arrTime": "10:32pm",
        "arrStation": "Allawah Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    }
],
[
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "9:23pm",
        "depStation": "Albion Park Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "9:45pm",
        "arrStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "1"
    },
    {
        "train": "South Coast train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "9:54pm",
        "depStation": "Wollongong Station ",
        "depPlatform": "1",
        "arrTime": "11:14pm",
        "arrStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    },
    {
        "train": "Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "11:30pm",
        "depStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "depPlatform": "3",
        "arrTime": "11:32pm",
        "arrStation": "Allawah Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    }
],
{
    "1": {
        "train": "Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ",
        "depTime": "5:09am+",
        "depStation": "Hurstville Station ",
        "depPlatform": "3",
        "arrTime": "5:11am+",
        "arrStation": "Allawah Station ",
        "arrPlatform": "3"
    }
}
```

]

when i am converting above data to Json format i am getting the following error

```
    06-11 18:36:40.584: V/Error(657): Error in parsing Innerorg.json.JSONException: Value {"1":{"depTime":"5:09am+","arrStation":"Allawah Station ","arrTime":"5:11am+","train":"Eastern Suburbs and Illawarra train (CityRail) ","arrPlatform":"3","depStation":"Hurstville Station ","depPlatform":"3"}} at 4 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

How to parse this type of **json** strings in Android. Any advice friends........?

Comment: your above json string is not valid paste [here and see](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Your json format is wrong.You can validate it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: json format is not valid, you can check json format from http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i have just entered format of the part of my json.Now i have updated the complete json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My string was like below

```
{
"result": "success",
"countryCodeList": [
{
"countryName": "World Wide",
"countryCode": "00"
},
{
"countryName": "Korea, Republic of",
"countryCode": "kr"
},
{
"countryName": "United States",
"countryCode": "us"
},-
{
"countryName": "Japan",
"countryCode": "jp"
},
{
"countryName": "China",
"countryCode": "cn"
},
{
"countryName": "India",
"countryCode": "in"
}
]
}
```

i have done

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);

JSONArray valArray1 = valArray.getJSONArray(1);

    valArray1.toString().replace("[", "");
            valArray1.toString().replace("]", "");

            int len = valArray1.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < valArray1.length(); i++) {

                Country country = new Country();
                JSONObject arr = valArray1.getJSONObject(i);

                country.setCountryCode(arr.getString("countryCode"));
                country.setCountryName(arr.getString("countryName"));
                arrCountries.add(country);
            }
```

Comment: I just entered part of the my string. actually its a valid json format. I have checked in http://www.jsonlint.org/. If you want you can check my string now

Answer (score 1):

That's because your JSON string is not well constructed.

Try to put it into this: http://jsonlint.com/ it will tell your current errors.

Also please read some documentations about JSON here http://json.org/ because your are actually making some basics error :)

If you also provide what your JSON has to rappresent I can show the correct form of your JSON string :)

Comment: Right. This Json contains 2 root elements, which is not valid.